# What is the difference between the `dataset.batch` function and the `batch_size` parameter of the `model.fit` function?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

What is the difference between batching your dataset with `dataset.batch(batch_size)` and batching your dataset with the `batch_size` parameter on the `.fit` the function of your model? do they have the same functionality or are they different?

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670041/batch-size-in-tf-model-fit-vs-batch-size-in-tf-data-dataset/62670148#62670148

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch\_size in tf model.fit() vs. batch\_size in tf.data.Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670041/batch-size-in-tf-model-fit-vs-batch-size-in-tf-data-dataset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for the parameter `batch_size` in [`fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

> **`batch_size`**
> Integer or `None`. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, `batch_size` will default to 32. Do not specify the `batch_size` if your data is in the form of datasets, generators, or [`keras.utils.Sequence`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) instances (since they generate batches).

So, if you are passing a dataset object for training, do not use the `batch_size` parameter, as that is only meant for the case where your X/Y values are NumPy arrays or TensorFlow tensors.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dataset.batch()` combines consecutive elements of a dataset object into batches. For example:

```
>> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(8)
>> dataset = dataset.batch(3)
>> list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
[array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7])]
```

This modifies your dataset object itself. In many instances, this may not be desirable. I would recommend using this function solely for manipulation of the dataset as a step in preprocessing.

Moreover, combining a dataset object with specifying the `batch_size` parameter in `fit` will throw an error.

The `batch_size` parameter should be used when numpy arrays or tensorflow tensors as passed as inputs to `fit`.

Examples taken from official tensorflow documentation which can be found at the links provided below.

`dataset.batch()` - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch